# Setting boolean variable to condition?

Tags: java, boolean

Is there any noticeable difference between

```
boolean foo= bar>1;
```

and

```
boolean foo = bar>1? true:false;
```

I have noticed that in the first example, the condition is evaluated immediately, looking something like this.

```
int bar=3;
boolean foo= bar>1;
bar =0;
if(foo){
    System.out.println("Foobar");
}
```

Would print `Foobar`, whereas if the condition were to be inside the `if` statement, it would not print at all. This so far is identical to giving the boolean variable a true/false value from the start with the ternary operator or `if/else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary is ***highly*** redundant.  Given that the inequality will return a boolean result, you do not need to perform any kind of ternary operation on it whatsoever.

Comment: That's what I thought, because I knew it wasn't evaluating the variable inside the if statement, I was just making sure there wasn't any extra nuance to it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I like to add along with, both of the code will **generate the same bytecode**. For the proof you can use the **Java Class File Disassembler (`javap`)**

use the command to disassemble the `class` files `javap -c com.package.MyClass` and you will find for the both of the code **JVM** will generate the same bytecode. Hence there is **No** benefit or harm for either of the two statement. But definitely **ternary here is redaundant**